# Outlook 2010 delayed sync with exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I have an exchange 2010 server with about 50 clients, most are using smartphones, tablets and everyone has Outlook 2010 on their desktops.

The problem i have been experiencing myself and others have reported is that e-mail deliveries are significantly delayed in Outlook but shows up and works instantly on the mobile devices.

Here's a typical configuration for a user

1. Outlook 2010 installed at Work PC
2. Outlook 2010 installed at Home PC
3. 1 or 2 tablets also configured for mobile email (via Wifi on same LAN as 1 or 2)
4. Mobile phone via carrier mobile data.

The problem
Someone sends an email, all locations show this email within a few seconds, no problem, However randomly throughout the day, Outlook at location 1 says "All folders are up to date" but emails have not synced for an hour or more. Location #2 is updated and mobiles are updated. The issue occurs at both location 1 and 2 only in Outlook. I want to rule out the network at these locations since the tablets are on the same network over WiFi and never have this issue, and the phones are connected over the carrier data network.

My Question.
What might be wrong with outlook ? I doubt there's a server side issue. Where do i start troubleshooting ?

Comment: what kinds of devices are between the work pc's and the exchange servers? routers? firewalls?

Comment: Have you recreated the profile. Or at the very least re-create the OST.

Comment: @t1nt1n - Yes, in fact 1 of the systems is a fresh clean install of Windows also.

Comment: @longneck - Exchange Server hosted offsite, home router on the edge of the network for home user and business class router for office locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by checking your AV settings on your systems. Symantec Endpoint Protection (and many other popular AV solutions) have an Outlook scanning feature that have caused issues similar to this.